# Application error when pushing rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So, my app works fine locally, but won't load when I push to Heroku (I get the standard Application Error).

Here's what Heroku logs throws... issue seems to be with Pony, but I don't have Pony installed as a gem anymore and the file app/config/initializers/Pony.rb doesn't exist. Any thoughts?

```
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976091+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/initializers/pony.rb:1:
in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Pony (NameError)
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976091+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976091+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976091+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen
t'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976091+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen
t_from'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976091+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976253+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976969+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2013-11-02T02:42:35.976969+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2013-11-02T02:42:35.976801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-11-02T02:42:37.108108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-11-02T02:42:37.142397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-11-02T02:42:40.089711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=quacklab.herokuapp.com fwd="24.52.218.163" dyno= co
nnect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-02T02:42:40.402078+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=quacklab.herokuapp.com fwd="24.52.218.16
3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-02T02:42:40.544050+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=quacklab.herokuapp.com fwd="24.52.218.16
3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-02T02:45:03+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-11-02T02:45:25.378838+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c1a539f by taylorscollon@gm
ail.com
2013-11-02T02:45:25.406765+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v15 created by taylorscoll
on@gmail.com
2013-11-02T02:45:25+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-11-02T02:45:25.854982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-11-02T02:45:30.985303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 30336 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-11-02T02:45:35.464823+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-11-02T02:45:35.462924+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-11-02T02:45:35.462924+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:30336
2013-11-02T02:45:35.468274+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.468168+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:En
gine>'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.468375+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.468693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.468474+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.468592+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.462924+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-11-02T02:45:35.467812+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/initializers/pony.rb:1:
in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Pony (NameError)
2013-11-02T02:45:35.468895+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen
t'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.469093+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.469407+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.469208+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.469308+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.469505+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.468994+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen
t_from'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.469857+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.469956+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470056+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470366+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.462924+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.469756+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470252+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470668+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.471200+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.471298+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470980+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470868+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.468792+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470770+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.471098+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.471495+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.471908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.471396+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2013-11-02T02:45:35.471594+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.471692+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.472108+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.471807+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.472208+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.472317+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.472007+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.469655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/
ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470154+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0
.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2013-11-02T02:45:35.470468+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir
e'
2013-11-02T02:45:36.978992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-11-02T02:45:37.012398+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-11-02T02:46:01.632458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=quacklab.herokuapp.com fwd="24.52.218.163" dyno= co
nnect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-02T02:46:01.960645+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=quacklab.herokuapp.com fwd="24.52.218.16
3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-02T02:46:02.126826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=quacklab.herokuapp.com fwd="24.52.218.16
3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: When you say "the file app/config/initializers/Pony.rb doesn't exist", did you `git rm` it and push that change to Heroku?

Comment: I can't git rm it because it doesn't exist. Like, it's just not a file, so running that throws a "did not match any files" error.

Comment: How about `pony.rb`? Lower case "p".

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you are using using Bundler 1.3.2. And that you are pushing both your Gemfile and your lock file.

Comment: I believe I'm running bundler 1.3.5 and I'm pushing both Gemfile and lock file.

Comment: Try cleaning the cache then as described here: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md. This post also describes working with Heroku specifically: http://artsy.github.io/blog/2013/01/15/debugging-bundler-issues-with-heroku/